# Best way to delete from two pk's (pivot) table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I have table design like this:

```
id_a    int(10) NO  PRI     
id_b    int(10) NO  PRI
```

For example: I want to delete data pair where one column contains '1' and second contains '2'.
but there are two possibilities:

```
1) id_a = 1, id_b = 2
2) id_a = 2, id_b = 1
```

And I newer know if '1' will be in column id_a or id_b. 
What is the best way to handle deletes like this?.

Comment: Does it mean you want to delete only when the id_a is greater than id_b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look for both:

```
WHERE (id_a = 1 AND id_b = 2) 
   OR (id_a = 2 AND id_b = 1)
```